# How to solve C# reference errors for Watson Unity SDK in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ibm-watson

This is my first Unity project and since I know a bit about Watson, I thought I would start with that.
But when I create a new project and import the Watson Unity SDK assets into the Mono environment I get errors like :

> Assets\unity-sdk-core-0.2.0\unity-sdk-core-0.2.0\Utilities\FrameRateCounter.cs(20,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'UI' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'UnityEngine' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

When I create a new C# script in the scenes folder, the assembly reference for UnityEngine.UI can be found.

When I open the FrameRateCounter.cs file in Visual Studio, I don't get this message.

I am running version 2019.3.0a3 Personal of Unity
[image]

Comment: Make sure MonoDevelop is selected as unity's External Script Editor in Unity (preferences -> External Tools -> External Script Editor). Then try closing monodevelop if it isn't already closed, then double clicking on a script in Unity to let it try and configure MonoDevelop.

Comment: Thanks @Ruzihm, this proofs I am really new at this. I have added the about Unity screenshot to the question. That is where I got Mono from. I have Visual Studio and VS Code to edit C# sharp files

Comment: I would try closing unity and visual studio, going into your project directory, and deleting the `Library` directory in there. then start unity and double click on a script in unity to let it try and rebuild everything.

Comment: @Ruzihm thanks for the tip, but unfortunately this did not resolve the issue. I think it is best if I take a few steps back and learn a bit more about the basics.